# SSL Certs Aren't Created Correctly in Java 11

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-11, tomcat9

I've been using Java to create SSL certificates for use in Tomcat for 12 years now.  I've used the same commands moving from 1.5 -> 1.6 -> 1.7 -> 1.8 without issues.  I recently upgraded to Java 11 and am trying to follow these same steps to create the certificate's CSR and then sign it.  In Java 11 I always get the same "`Public keys in reply and keystore don't match`" error at the last step.

Commands to create keystore/CSR

```
set KEYTOOL=C:\software\<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool

call %KEYTOOL% -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore %KEY%.keystore

call %KEYTOOL% -certreq -sigalg SHA256withRSA -alias tomcat -file temp.csr -keystore %KEY%.keystore
```

Commands to sign keystore

```
set KEYTOOL=C:\software\<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool

call %KEYTOOL% -import -alias intermediate -keystore %KEY%.keystore -trustcacerts -file %intermediate%.crt

call %KEYTOOL% -import -alias tomcat -keystore %KEY%.keystore -trustcacerts -file %CERT%.crt
```

These commands work successfully in Java 1.8 but fail in Java 11.  Same certificate being sent back by my client.

Have the steps to create and sign certificates changed in Java 11?

Comment: To be clear, you didn't create the cert; you created a keypair and CSR and without saying so sent the CSR to a CA which created the cert and returned it, with chain cert(s) if needed which one apparently is, and you're trying to use it. That said, **NO these commands have not changed in j11** and the sequence you show (plus the omitted step of talking to the CA) should work if you use consistent filenames (in your case env vars) and does for me. Check that you are using the correct filenames and file contents. ...

Comment: ... If you have or get OpenSSL compare `openssl req -in temp.csr -noout -pubkey |openssl md5` to `openssl x509 -in %CERT%.crt -noout -pubkey |openssl md5`